# Modify Memory Configuration Registers

Tags: linux, memory, intel, bios, power-management

I have an `Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4720HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz` (`Haswell`) processor on my `Asus` Laptop. The chipset datasheets include [Datasheet, volume 1 (M- and H-processor lines)](https://cdrdv2.intel.com/v1/dl/getcontent/328901) and [Datasheet, volume 2 (M- and H-processor lines)](https://cdrdv2.intel.com/v1/dl/getcontent/328902). I want to use `DRAM` *Power-Down Modes*. They are described in **page 64** of *volume 1*:

[image]

There seems to be a `PM_PDWN_config_0_0_0_MCHBAR` register to control this power management mechanism. At the bottom of the same page, it is mentioned that they can only be changed if the `BIOS` does not lock the `IMC` registers:

[image]

And the description for `PM_PDWN` register can be found on **page 247** of *volume 2*, as shown below:

[image]

I read the value of this register in a *kernel module* using `ioread32()` and it was `0x6080`. But I could not modify any of the bits (using `iowrite32()`). As can be seen in the figure above, the access method for the meaningful bits (i.e., bits `0-15`) is `RW_L`. The definition is mentioned in **table 2 on page 18** of *volume 2*:

[image]

This possibly means that the register is locked by the `BIOS`. I also updated the `BIOS` firmware and there was nothing seemingly related to these bits.

The same is true for the *Self-Refresh* configuration register (**page 252** of *volume 2*):

[image]

The access methods are also `RW_L` and the retrieved value, `0x10200`, can not be modified.

**Does this mean that I can not change any of the bits with an `RW_L` flag?**

In other words, can I do any **manual** DRAM power management?
If the reason is a `BIOS` lock, can I write a `UEFI` application and **unlock** the register? The `BIOS` seems to be **too** aggressive, here. **None** of the `RW_L` bits of the registers that I tested could be modified.

Comment: As a general rule, the BIOS locks **all** hardware configuration registers. Some BIOSes have options to tweak this kind of thing, but I don’t know if any have an option to leave them unlocked. Look for it in the BIOS advanced setup menus. If not, you would have to build a custom BIOS to avoid locking them, which is quite an undertaking even if you know how to do it.

Comment: Thanks! So you mean that even a *`UEFI` application* will not work. Because, **here**, `RW-L` means the bit is locked **permanently** and this happens **before** the *application* is run.

Comment: What is the **most unrestricted** `BIOS` firmware?